# Turi Create suffering Excessive Memory Usage with no Progress

Tags: python, coreml, turi-create

I have been trying to create a simple Core ML model using Turi Create, but the program stops after iterating. I have a folder called 'RenderedImages' which contains folders with their label name with all their relevant images.

The code:

```
import turicreate as tc

print("Processing images for training...")            
# load the images
labels = list(poses)
def get_label(path, labels=labels):  
    for label in labels:  
        if label in path:  
            return label

data = tc.image_analysis.load_images('RenderedImages', with_path = True)
data['label'] = data['path'].apply(get_label)
print(data.groupby('label',[tc.aggregate.COUNT]))

# save the data
sFramePath = 'Data.sframe'
data.save(sFramePath)
data.explore()

#Train the model

print("Training model..") 
# load the data
data = tc.SFrame(sFramePath)
train_data, test_data = data.random_split(0.8)
model = tc.image_classifier.create(
    train_data,
    target='label',
    model='squeezenet_v1.1',
    max_iterations=500)
print("ENDED")
model.save('MyModel.model')
model.export_coreml('Data.mlmodel')

predictions = model.predict(test_data)
metrics = model.evaluate(test_data)
print(metrics['accuracy'])
```

The output is:

> Materializing SFrame...
>   Done.
>   Training model..
>   [19:49:50] src/nnvm/legacy_json_util.cc:190: Loading symbol saved by previous version v0.8.0. Attempting to upgrade...
>   [19:49:50] src/nnvm/legacy_json_util.cc:198: Symbol successfully upgraded!
>   Resizing images...
>   Performing feature extraction on resized images...
>   Completed 154/154
>   PROGRESS: Creating a validation set from 5 percent of training data. This may take a while.
>             You can set `validation_set=None` to disable validation tracking.
>
> WARNING: The number of feature dimensions in this problem is very large in comparison with the number of examples. Unless an appropriate regularization value is set, this model may not provide accurate predictions for a validation/test set.
>
> ### Logistic regression:
>
> Number of examples          : 143
>   Number of classes           : 31
>   Number of feature columns   : 1
>   Number of unpacked features : 1000
>   Number of coefficients      : 30030
>
> ### Starting L-BFGS
>
> +-----------+----------+-----------+--------------+-------------------+---------------------+
>   | Iteration | Passes   | Step size | Elapsed Time | Training-accuracy | Validation-accuracy |
>   +-----------+----------+-----------+--------------+-------------------+---------------------+
>   | 1         | 6        | 0.000111  | 1.190632     | 0.076923          | 0.000000            |
>   | 2         | 8        | 1.000000  | 1.284117     | 0.076923          | 0.000000            |
>   | 3         | 9        | 1.000000  | 1.342702     | 0.111888          | 0.090909            |
>   | 4         | 10       | 1.000000  | 1.400136     | 0.412587          | 0.181818            |
>   | 5         | 11       | 1.000000  | 1.463703     | 0.426573          | 0.181818            |
>   | 6         | 12       | 1.000000  | 1.511046     | 0.601399          | 0.454545            |
>   | 11        | 17       | 1.000000  | 1.800922     | 0.853147          | 0.272727            |
>   | 25        | 33       | 0.500000  | 2.653545     | 0.930070          | 0.454545            |
>   | 50        | 65       | 0.500000  | 4.236037     | 1.000000          | 0.545455            |
>   | 51        | 69       | 0.250000  | 4.388548     | 1.000000          | 0.545455            |
>   | 75        | 103      | 0.500000  | 5.984408     | 1.000000          | 0.545455            |
>   | 100       | 142      | 1.000000  | 7.716398     | 1.000000          | 0.545455            |
>   | 101       | 144      | 1.000000  | 7.792923     | 1.000000          | 0.545455            |
>   | 125       | 171      | 1.000000  | 9.240253     | 1.000000          | 0.545455            |
>   +-----------+----------+-----------+--------------+-------------------+---------------------+
>
> SUCCESS: Optimal solution found.

Then after this point, the memory fills up completely and nothing happens after even if I wait a while.

I have 16GB of memory, and to make sure the amount of images wasn't the issue I even ran it with 5 images per label (so in total about 50 images). My computer and memory I don't think is the issue, so what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for any answers

---

**UPDATE**

I found out what the issue is! Although, I don't know how to solve it.

This section:

```
def get_label(path, labels=labels):  
    for label in labels:  
        if label in path:  
            return label

data['label'] = data['path'].apply(get_label)
```

Does **NOT** correctly label all the images based on their file path. 
This is because something like this

```
data["foodType"] = data["path"].apply(lambda path: "Rice" if "rice" in path else "Soup")
```

works, but using this method I can only have 2 different labels (2 different folders), but I want more.
Is there any way to label images depending on the name of the folder they are in with more than 2 folders?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are using squeezenet_v1.1 will be much better that other model. you may try to comment data.explore() by

```
# data.explore()
```

This is just the visualisation all your images in turi may cause you memory issues (if your dataset have lot images).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but unfortunately it didn't work - it didn't change the memory usage much

Comment: I have found out what the issue is now! I don't know how to fix it though, maybe you have some ideas. I edited my original post with the issue